# is there a way to put comments in a unix command line?

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a program (in python) that calls a separate program (via subprocess). I'm finding that in some cases the sub program is getting stuck running. I can see the sub-program by running top, and if i press "c", I can see the full command line.

What I want, is to be able to stick debugging data (like current thread id, etc) in the command line when i'm calling the sub program, so I can futher debug my problem.

Is there a way to put comments in command line arguments such that they show up in top?

Comment: Any reason you can't write that information to a log file?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a direct way but you could write a little shell script to which you pass the actual command to run plus argument *and* debugging information. It would show up in the top/ps output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making them comments, put them in the environment.  For example, if you have a `/proc` file system, you could do:

```
FOO=value cmd
```

When top shows the pid of the command, do:

```
tr '\000' '\012' < /proc/pid/environ | grep FOO
```

to see the value of FOO in the environment of the cmd.  If the values contain newlines, you will need to be more careful about the display, something like:

```
perl -n0E 'say if /FOO/' /proc/pid/environ
```